# Reset counter after each post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, counter, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having an ACF repeater inside a custom post type loop with a counter that makes a row around every two col-md-6's. This works great when I have an even number of col's but not when it's uneven. When a post has an uneven number of col's the counter somehow remembers that for the next post and only displays one col in the first row.

Down here you'll find the current code and a little picture of what is happening.
Somehow I need to reset the counter after each post loop but can't figure it out. wp_reset_postdata doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'posttypename', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php if( have_rows('row') ): ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php while( have_rows('row') ): the_row(); $text = get_sub_field('text'); ?>

                <div class="col-md-6">      
                    <?php echo $text; ?>
                </div>

                <?php $counter++; if($counter % 2 === 0) :  echo '</div> <div class="row">'; endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change. You need to make sure that your counter is reset to 0 before the loop for the `acf` starts.

```
        <?php $counter = 0; //Initialize your Counter here before the Loop Starts for each Post ?> 
        <?php if( have_rows('row') ): ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php while( have_rows('row') ): the_row(); $text = get_sub_field('text'); ?>

                <div class="col-md-6">      
                    <?php echo $text; ?>
                </div>

                <?php $counter++; if($counter % 2 === 0) :  echo '</div> <div class="row">'; endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```